# U- SQL Unable to extract data from JSON file

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I was trying to extract data from a JSON file using USQL. Either the query runs successfully without producing any output data or results in "vertex failed fast error".

The JSON file looks like:

```js
{
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "Sales/Account",
      "id": "7367e3f2-e1a5-11e5-80e8-0933ecd4cd8c",
      "deviceName": "HP",
      "deviceModel": "g6-pavilion",
      "clientip": "0.41.4.1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sales/Account",
      "id": "c01efba0-e0d5-11e5-ae20-af6dc1f2c036",
      "deviceName": "acer",
      "deviceModel": "veriton",
      "clientip": "10.10.14.36"
    }
  ]
}
```

And my U-SQL script is

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

DECLARE @in string="adl://xyz.azuredatalakestore.net/todelete.json";

DECLARE @out string="adl://xyz.azuredatalakestore.net/todelete.tsv";

@trail2=EXTRACT results string FROM @in USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

@jsonify=SELECT Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(results,"name","id","deviceName","deviceModel","clientip") AS rec FROM @trail2;

@logSchema=SELECT rec["name"] AS sysName,
              rec["id"] AS sysId,
              rec["deviceName"] AS domainDeviceName,
              rec["deviceModel"] AS domainDeviceModel,
              rec["clientip"] AS domainClientIp 
       FROM @jsonify;

OUTPUT @logSchema TO @out USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually the `JSONExtractor` supports the rowpath parameter expressed in [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) that gives you the ability to identify the JSON object or JSON array items that you want to map into rows. So you can extract your data with a single statement from your JSON document:

```
@logSchema = 
    EXTRACT name string, id string, deviceName string, deviceModel string, clientip string
    FROM @input
   USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor("results[*]");
```

Answer (score 2):

Sarath,

the problem was that your @trail2 output was a json array "[{...},{...}]" which the JsonFunction can't parse, as far as I can tell. So I outputted that to a file and reread it with the inputter, which can parse arrays.

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

DECLARE @in string="adl://xyz.azuredatalakestore.net/todelete.json";
DECLARE @out string="adl://xyz.azuredatalakestore.net/todelete.tsv";
DECLARE @mid string="adl://xyz.azuredatalakestore.net/intermediate.txt";


@trail2=EXTRACT results string FROM @in USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

OUTPUT @trail2 TO @mid USING Outputters.Text(quoting:false);

@jsonify=EXTRACT name string,
                id string, 
                deviceName string ,
                deviceModel string,
                clientip string
FROM @mid USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

@logSchema=SELECT name AS sysName,
              id AS sysId,
              deviceName AS domainDeviceName,
              deviceModel AS domainDeviceModel,
              clientip AS domainClientIp 
       FROM @jsonify;

OUTPUT @logSchema TO @out USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

Comment: You can do it more efficiently without intermediate files (that actually require you to submit two jobs since scripts cannot read data that it creates). See my alternative answer.

Comment: _scripts cannot read data that it creates_ then how is he doing `OUTPUT` followed by an `EXTRACT` against the same resource, `@mid`  ??!?!?!