# U-SQL - Extract data from complex json object

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

So I have a lot of json files structured like this:

```
{
    "Id": "2551faee-20e5-41e4-a7e6-57bd20b02a22",
    "Timestamp": "2016-12-06T08:09:57.5541438+01:00",
    "EventEntry": {
        "EventId": 1,
        "Payload": [
            "1a3e0c9e-ef69-4c6a-ac8c-9b2de2fbc701",
            "DHS.PlanCare.Business.BusinessLogic.VisionModels.VisionModelServiceWithoutUnitOfWork.FetchVisionModelsForClientOnReferenceDateAsync(System.Int64 clientId, System.DateTime referenceDate, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)",
            25,
            "DHS.PlanCare.Business.BusinessLogic.VisionModels.VisionModelServiceWithoutUnitOfWork+<FetchVisionModelsForClientOnReferenceDateAsync>d__11.MoveNext\r\nDHS.PlanCare.Core.Extensions.IQueryableExtensions+<ExecuteAndThrowTaskCancelledWhenRequestedAsync>d__16`1.MoveNext\r\n",
            false,
            "2197, 6-12-2016 0:00:00, System.Threading.CancellationToken"
        ],
        "EventName": "Duration",
        "KeyWordsDescription": "Duration",
        "PayloadSchema": [
            "instanceSessionId",
            "member",
            "durationInMilliseconds",
            "minimalStacktrace",
            "hasFailed",
            "parameters"
        ]
    },
    "Session": {
        "SessionId": "0016e54b-6c4a-48bd-9813-39bb040f7736",
        "EnvironmentId": "C15E535B8D0BD9EF63E39045F1859C98FEDD47F2",
        "OrganisationId": "AC6752D4-883D-42EE-9FEA-F9AE26978E54"
    }
}
```

How can I create an u-sql query that outputs the

```
Id, 
Timestamp, 
EventEntry.EventId and 
EventEntry.Payload[2] (value 25 in the example below)
```

I can't figure out how to extend my query

```
@extract =
     EXTRACT 
         Timestamp DateTime
     FROM @"wasb://xxx/2016/12/06/0016e54b-6c4a-48bd-9813-39bb040f7736/yyy/{*}/{*}.json"
     USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

@res =
    SELECT Timestamp
    FROM @extract;

OUTPUT @res TO "/output/result.csv" USING Outputters.Csv();
```

I have seen some examples like:

[U- SQL Unable to extract data from JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913685/u-sql-unable-to-extract-data-from-json-file) => this only queries one level of the document, I need data from multiple levels.

[U-SQL - Extract data from json-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147932/u-sql-extract-data-from-json-array) => this only queries one level of the document, I need data from multiple levels.

Comment: may be this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198694/accesing-nested-properties-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONTuple` supports multiple JSONPaths in one go.

```
@extract =
     EXTRACT
         Id String,
         Timestamp DateTime,
         EventEntry String
     FROM @"..."
     USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

@res =
    SELECT Id, Timestamp, EventEntry,
    Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(EventEntry,
        "EventId", "Payload[2]") AS Event
    FROM @extract;

@res =
    SELECT Id,
    Timestamp,
    Event["EventId"] AS EventId,
    Event["Payload[2]"] AS Something
    FROM @res;
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this GIT example. https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/JsonSample/JsonSample/NestedJsonParsing.usql

This take 2 disparate data elements and combines them, like you have the Payload, and Payload schema. If you create key value pairs using the "Donut" or "Cake and Batter" examples you may be able to match the scema up to the payload and use the cross apply explode function.

Comment: Although this does not answer my answer directly it provides some useful examples, thanks!